# Does CONN_MAX_AGE have an effect when using unix sockets in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, sockets

[Django deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#persistent-database-connections) mentions enabling persistent database connections using CONN_MAX_AGE.

What it doesn't mention, and I wasn't able to find anything related to it, is whether it is needed / has any effect on performance when using unix sockets to the database, not TCP.

I'm using this unix socket configuration via `postgresql_psycopg2`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '...',
        'USER': '...',
        'PASSWORD': '...',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Does CONN_MAX_AGE have an effect when using unix sockets in Django?